# how to find date difference result in minutes

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a date field in my table.Now i want to check if currentTime -DbDatetime > xminutes.How can i do it in sql hibernate

```
query = session.creatQuery(Select x from Xabc where :currentTime- abcDateTime > 20 )
query.setParameter("currentTime",new Date())
```

Comment: If the underlying database is Oracle, i would try: where (:currentTime - abcDateTime)*24*60 >20

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the easy way is to calculate it in Java, as for example

```
new Date( new Date().getTime() - (20 * 60000));
```

I also found in Google the following snippet

```
from ApplData data where (day(current_date()) - day(data.myDate)) > 15
```

It seems that you can use expressions with date functions and Hibernate has plenty of them

> current_date(), current_time(), current_timestamp(),
>    second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), year(...)

Refer to the manual

Comment: Except use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of creating a throw-away `Date` object just to call `getTime()` on it.